# Did rails 5 drop it's support for rest client gem?

Tags: ruby, rest-client, ruby-on-rails-5

Today when I tried to use the `RestClient` in my freshly installed rails project I got an err. Then I thought I had to import it so I did require 'rest-client' and also got an err. But when I installed it in my gem file and then the problem resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *support* for rest client gem in the Rails. You can check the [Gemfile](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/Gemfile). I assume you are talking about the Ruby gem, if so, you can find all related information in the [documentation](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) for `rest-client` gem.

Comment: oh. so rest client was not added by default in rails 4 as well ?

Comment: `Rails != Ruby` Rails  has no such gem `rest-client` in the dependencies.

Comment: ya u r right. I  just checked the gemfile for the 4.2 release. Thanks